# Assign value at pointer value from void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have two void pointers inside structures.

```
typedef struct DATA_T {
  BOOLEAN trigger;
  void *var_p;
  void *data_p;
} DATA_T;

typedef struct ITEM_T {
  DATA_T job_data[100];
  BOOLEAN job_active;
  BOOLEAN job_send;
} ITEM_T;

ITEM_T foo[100];
```

I assigned the two void pointers to different addresses.  Now, I have a value at one pointer and want to set the other pointer = to that value.

```
foo[i].job_data[j]->data_p = *(int*)foo[i].job_data[j].var_p;
```

This error is then posted:

```
error C2232: '->data_p' : left operand has 'struct' type, use '.'
```

I don't believe I want a `.` in place of the `->` here, because I need to dereference the pointer `data_p`.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You say that you "want to dereference data_p" , however it is not possible to dereference a `void *`.  (If that was possible then you would do it by writing `*(foo[i].job.data[j].data_p)`, where the parentheses are redundant but I added them for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because `job_data[j]` is not a pointer. It is a `DATA_T`. So the left-hand side should be `foo[i].job_data[j].data_p =` .

However there is another error. On the right-hand side, `*(int *)` produces an `int`, which cannot be stored in a `void *`.

If you want  to make the two pointers point to the same place then remove the `*(int *)`.

If both pointers actually point to `int`s, and you want to copy the pointed-to value on both sides, then put `*(int *)` on both sides.

Comment: Alright, one problem solved.  One more to go.  Editing post.I don't want them to point to the same place.  I want the value from one, set to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of job_data array are not pointers, they're in the type of DATA_T.